# how does facebook upload a photo when a user selects a file in the upload file dialog?

Tags: jquery, facebook, file-upload

When you update your profile picture on facebook, after selecting 'upload picture', the upload file dialog opens.  **Once you select a file in the dialog, your profile picture is then updated.**

Using jquery I've been able to trigger the click event on a hidden file input to open the upload file dialog.  I've also been able to wire up the change event on the file inputs upload file dialog (which fires once a user selects a file).  If I trigger a form submit action in the change event, IE barks access denied and the file is never uploaded.

I have tried an Iframe solution where the file input resides on another page and have invoked the click, change, and submit events from the parent page - and the file still isn't uploaded.

How does facebook's upload profile picture feature manage to get around this?  Any insight on where I should start?

Comment: Are you using async file upload ? if you are using async file upload you can trigger upload when user selects the image asynchronously and it will be uploaded/saved to the server, it means you don't have to call form submit event.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the best I have seen. I am using it in my current project:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload